# DocuSign RestApi - Error while uploading document - TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT

Tags: c#, xml, docusignapi

I'm getting the following error when I try to apply a template (created in my web account) to the document I'm trying to upload.

"DocumentId specified in the tab element does not refer to a document in this envelope. Tab refers to DocumentId 41791752 which is not present."

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the code I have:

```html
string xmlBody = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                "<emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request"</emailSubject>" +
                "<status>sent</status>" +   // "sent" to send immediately, "created" to save as draft in your account
                   "<compositeTemplates>" +
                       "<compositeTemplate>" +
                           "<serverTemplates>" +
                                  "<serverTemplate>" +
                                       "<sequence>1</sequence>" +
                                       "<templateId>" + templateID + "</templateId>" +
                                  "</serverTemplate>" +
                           "</serverTemplates>" +
                           "<inlineTemplates>" +
                                  "<inlineTemplate>" +
                                      "<sequence>2</sequence>" +
                                      "<recipients>" +                                        
                                           "<signers>" +
                                                  "<signer>" +
                                                        "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
                                                        "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>" +
                                                        "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +
                                                        "<roleName>Signer</roleName>" +
                                                   "</signer>" +
                                             "</signers>" +                                       
                                       "</recipients>" +
                                  "</inlineTemplate>" +
                          "</inlineTemplates>" +
                           "<document>" +
                                 "<name>" + documentName + "</name>" +
                                 "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                          "</document>" +
                    "</compositeTemplate>" +
                   "</compositeTemplates>" +
               "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

Comment: You have an error in following line : "<emailSubject>\"DocuSign API - Signature Request\"</emailSubject>" +

Comment: I fixed the emailSubject error as you suggested but I'm still getting the above error "tab refers to missing document". If I add <documents> node before <document> then the error goes away but it emails server template instead of the actual document that I'm sending with the API call. Any ideas on why it would not attach the document?

Comment: The xml file parsed correctly when I tested it yesterday.  I had to add properties for templateID, recipientEmail, recipentName, and documentName for my parsing code to work.  I used XDocument.Parse(xmlBody).  From the error message it sounds like the property documentName isn't set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you quoted:

> DocumentId specified in the tab element does not refer to a document in this envelope. Tab refers to DocumentId 41791752 which is not present.

I suggest that the template is referring to that documentId. But you're registering your document as Id 1.

Try changing

```
  "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
to
  "<documentId>41791752</documentId>" +
```

Comment: if I change documentID to 41791752 it adds the template document (stored in my web account) to the envelope instead of the actual document. I would like to apply server template to the new document that I'm sending through API call

Comment: This solution worked for me! My use case is for using the template to place the tabs. and overriding the template document with the one I am uploading. Thanks