# DocuSign API Replace template document but keep fields

Tags: php, docusignapi

I want to use the existing fields from a server template over another document.

At first I tried attaching the document at the same level as inline/server.
If I have the signer defined it gives me a 400 error, if I leave it off (did by accident) it completely wipes out the fields and shows the attached document.

Second I tried attaching the document to the inline template but that results in the attached document not appearing, it just operates like normal.

**update**

After adding additional debugging and research I now know that attaching it to the inline template was incorrect.  After adding debug to read the 400 response I am getting this error:

> "The DocumentId specified in the tab element does not refer to a document in this envelope. Tab refers to DocumentId 32475214 which is not present."

DocumentId is being set to 1 which is apparently wrong.

Which led me to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610216/docusign-restapi-error-while-uploading-document-tab-refers-to-missing-docume) on SO. In which a comment mentions that the ID kicked back from the 400 should be used.
After I hard coded this ID I see the replacement operation is a success!

However I now need to find a way find and to plug that value in programatically.

**Detail**

I am using the DocuSign [php sdk](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client) to help me build the data structure and access the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [listTemplateDocuments](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/templates/templatedocuments/list/) API to retrieve the documentId for the template.

The **documentId** retrieved in the above step should be used in the CompositeTemplate of [CreateEnvelope](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/) request

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Tabs should remain from the Server Template",
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "document": {
            "documentId": "<document Id>", //Use the documentId retrieved using the listTemplateDocuments api
            "name": "Replaced Document",
            "fileExtension": "txt",
            "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP"
        },
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "<Server Template Id Here>"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```