# createEnvelope class create only first Docusign document not others

Tags: php, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am trying to create the multiple document and I am getting the complete document in the envelop_definition array but when it will generate the docusign envelope then it is showing only first one.

What do I need to do it?

I am using below code for multiple documents.

```
$docs = array();
                    $b=1;
                    foreach ($fileArray as $key => $file) {

                    // Add a document to the envelope
                    $document = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document();
                    $document->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
                    $document->setName('Document '.$b);
                    $document->setDocumentId($b);
                    $document->setOrder($b);
                    $docs[] = $document;
                        # code...
                    $b++;
                    }





    $envelop_definition->setDocuments($docs);
            $envelop_definition->setTemplateRoles($all_template_roles);

            // send notification about status change 
            $envelop_definition->setEventNotification($event_notification);
            // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
            $envelop_definition->setStatus("sent");

$envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelop_definition, $options);
```

but getting only first document.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of a `templateRoles` object implies that you're trying to create an envelope that uses an already created template.

If that's the case then you do not add documents to the envelope/template by using the Document model.

Instead, you composite together the documents and the document(s) in the template.

If you're adding a document to the set of documents already in the template, see [eg013AddDocToTemplate.sh](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-curl/blob/master/examples/eg013AddDocToTemplate.sh) for a code example. The example is also available in [multiple languages](https://github.com/docusign?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=eg-03&type=&language=). PHP is in production.

If you're substituting a new document for one already in the template, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43828389/64904).